# Custom animation in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering if it's possible to use custom animation in Sencha Touch 2. If I've done my homework correctly, then Sencha Touch by default does not provide any help with animation apart from the fade-in/out, sliders and other simple UI elements.

One would have to use CSS3 for animations, right? I wan't to use an animation (let's say something like this : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-timing-function3) in my app.

I wan't the animation to load just after the initial loading screen but I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone help me out with the code? ELI5 please,since I'm new to ST, CSS and HTML5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok @user1324579 this steps are:

1. Create a CSS3 class
2. Create one panel Sencha
3. On html tag put class CSS

   ```
   var panel = new Ext.Panel({
      id: 'yourIdPanel',
      fullscreen: true,
      style: 'background-color:#ffffff',
      html: '<div class="animation_css_class"></div>'
   })
   ```
4. To load you just after the initial loading screen with id panel above or,

   ```
   var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
       id:'pnlInicio',
       fullscreen:true,
       items : [panel],
       dockedItems: []
   })
   ```

I hope these helps. :)

Comment: Great, that works..I didn't use the panels directly but I got an idea what you were suggesting and used it in a similar way. Thanks!

Comment: These are ST1 ways to create component. Better use Ext.create now

Answer (score 5):

In your launch function, you need to define you [Ext.Anim](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Anim) like so :

```
anim = Ext.create('Ext.Anim',{
  autoClear: false,
  from:{'left':'0px'},
  to: {'left':'100px'},
  delay: 1000,
  duration: 1000
});
```

Then you can [run](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Anim-method-run) this animation on any component (here on a Ext.Panel) like so :

```
anim.run(this.getView().element);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering..I used hekomobile's method of using CSS classes and that worked. I'll try out ext.anim too. Thanks!

Comment: i think this is the better approach as according to the docs it takes all the css values and is provided within the framework